# Mysql query returning NULL value when getting multiple row as result

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my query

```
 SELECT `months`,SUM(`price`) AS price 
 FROM `billing` 
 WHERE months='January' AND months='Feb'
```

I am trying to get result but this query is returning value NULL

Comment: `months` can't be January and February at __the same time__

Comment: @u_mulder Are you telling me PHP doesn't support rips in space time?

Comment: Real strange that "January" is written out completely but not "Feb" (February). Your question is too unclear. Post your db schema and values.

Comment: @u_mulder I think you meant: *"can't be January and Feb at the same time"* - Question's too unclear, IMHO as per their query. See my above comment to them.

Comment: I want to do sum of all price which are belongs to Jan to dec (months might be repeated several time) with the help of mysql query without using php code

Comment: Up until that you can provide us with what I asked, your question will remain unanswered. There's also no php here. `January` and `Jan` are two different animals.

Comment: Am also wondering if you're not storing those months in the same row(s).

Comment: The fact that you " want to get result with AND" is simply not possible. AS @u_mulder said, a column can't have two values at the same time. It seems like "months" is a field with a long text and you want to check for the two words in there. To have a more clear idea you have to include the schema and/or some data.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: finally got answer of my question....                                                        SELECT `months`,sum(`price`) as price FROM `billing` GROUP BY months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I got answer of my question
ans is:
SELECT `months`,sum(`price`) as price FROM `billing` GROUP BY months

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to show the result for the months of January and February, your query should look like:

```
SELECT months, SUM(price) AS price 
FROM billing 
WHERE months='January' OR months='Feb'
```

Also, you can use:

```
SELECT months, SUM(price) AS price 
FROM billing 
WHERE months IN ('January', 'Feb')
```

This second option will do the same since it will retrieve all the entries which "months" field matches with any value in the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might want to use `OR`

```
SELECT `months`,SUM(`price`) AS price 
 FROM `billing` 
 WHERE months='January' OR months='Feb'
```

Comment: No I  don't want to use OR I want to get result with AND